# Bootstrap Modal goes into the navbar area of my website, rather than to the center

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

http://dmidland.byethost5.com/dmidlandProto2/step4brad.php

I can't recognize the error. I have this problem for quite a while now, I just fix the stuff I use in here using a bunch of line breaks. But now I used a Bootstrap Modal, I need it to appear in the center. I tried experimenting in the code, but I can't really do anything.

Kindly inspect element the page and kindly tell me what seems to be the error and which code should I change..

thank you!! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line of css:

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Your `modal` is actually being positioned correctly. But your `navbar` is on top of the `modal` because of the `z-index` property. Either find a way to decrease the `z-index` property of the `navbar`, or add a higher z-index to `#myModal`.

For example, you could just add this to your css:

```
#myModal {
  z-index:100000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Kenny there is an issue with your navabar its z-index is more than the modal
so please increase the z-index of modal or decrease the z-index of navbar.

#myModal{z-index: 999999 !important;}